# How to add third party external script and inline script together in <head> in NextJS 14 (appDir)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I'm looking for a solution to add my advertisement scrips in my NextJS 14 application (appDir)

Also, the script must be added in the <head> tag and I want to re-run these scripts every time the route changes.

scripts example:

```
\<script async src="https://example.com/third-party.js"\>\</script\>  
\<script\>

///Code Block///

\</script\>
```

I already tried multiple things like creating a script tag on the client side via `UseEffect`, also tried the `NextJS` Script component but did not get the expected results.

Comment: By "I want to re-run these scripts every time the route changes" do you mean the page refreshes or something specific you are not showing?  Certainly a minimal example that might not be enough to go on here perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

After scratching my head for some time I was finally able to figure out a way to make this work.

In the client component, I've just added an `useEffect` and inside the function when the components get mounts, I just created a script tag and append this child `script` tag to the document's `head`

for example:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag.src = "/js/script.js";
    scriptTag.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);

    let rampScriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    rampScriptTag.src = "https://example.com/third-party.js";
    rampScriptTag.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(rampScriptTag);
    console.log("route changed!");
    return (()=>{
      //You can also add your cleanup function when unmounting
    })
  }, []);
```

for the inline script, I just made a separate .js/.ts file in the public folder and put the content in the file.

I hope this helps someone